# Degree of extension $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p),\sin(2\pi/p))/\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p))$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $p$ be an odd prime number. I want to compute the degree
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p),\sin(2\pi/p)):\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p))].
$$
I already showed that
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p)):\mathbb{Q}] = \frac{p-1}{2},
$$
so it will be helpful to know
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p),\sin(2\pi/p)):\mathbb{Q}].
$$
We know that the polynomial
$$
X^2+\cos^2(2\pi/p)-1 \in \mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p))[X]
$$
vanish on $\sin(2\pi/p)$, but I don't how to show that this polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p))$. I believe that 
$$
[\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p),\sin(2\pi/p)):\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p))]=2,
$$
but I cannot see why it is possible or not to write
$$
\sin(2\pi/p) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_k\cos^k(2\pi/p)
$$
for some $a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Is it not always two? After all, $\sin^2\theta=1-\cos^2\theta$. (Maybe in exceptional cases, the degree might be one…)

Comment: Exactly, but are there such exceptional cases?

Comment: Well, I was thinking of $\theta=30^\circ$, but that does not come from a prime-numbered division of the circle.

Comment: first thoughts: $X^2-\cos(2\pi/p)-1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p))$ iff it has a root in $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p))$ iff $\sqrt{1-\cos^2(2\pi/p)} \in \mathbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/p))$ iff there exist $a_0,\dots,a_n \in \mathbb{Q}$ with $\sqrt{1-\cos^2(2\pi/p)} = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k\cos^k(2\pi/p)$. Suppose such $a_0,\dots,a_n$ exist. Then, $1-\cos^2(2\pi/p) = \sum_{k,k'=0}^n a_ka_{k'}\cos^{k+k'}(2\pi/p)$. Let $b_m = \sum_{0 \le k,k' \le n : k+k'=m} a_ka_{k'}$ for $m \not = 0,2$, and $b_2 = \sum_{0 \le k,k' \le n : k+k'=2} a_ka_{k'}+1$ and $b_0 = a_0^2-1$.

Comment: Then $\sum_{m=0}^{2n} b_m\cos^m(2\pi/p) = 0$, implying $x^p-1$ divides $\sum_{m=0}^{2n} b_m x^m$. idk if this goes anywhere, just felt like commenting it.

Comment: $p$ stands for arbitrary prime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $\zeta_p$ the p-th primitive root of unity we have that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p,i):\mathbb{Q}]$ is equal to:

$$[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p,i):\mathbb{Q}(\cos2\pi/p,\sin2\pi/p)][\mathbb{Q}(\cos2\pi/p,\sin2\pi/p):\mathbb{Q}(\cos2\pi/p)][\mathbb{Q}(\cos2\pi/p):\mathbb{Q}]$$

Now, since $i$ cannot be in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$ (why?), we have that  $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p,i):\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)]=2$ because $i$ is the root of the an irreducible quadratic. Since $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p):\mathbb{Q}]=p-1$, we see that the entire expression above is equal to $2(p-1)$. Note that $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p,i):\mathbb{Q}(\cos2\pi/p,\sin2\pi/p)]$ is degree $2$ because $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p,i)=\mathbb{Q}(\cos2\pi/p,\sin2\pi/p,i)$ (why?) and $\mathbb{Q}(\cos2\pi/p,\sin2\pi/p)$ is real.

Putting this all together, and by your previous computation we have that $2(p-1)=2[\mathbb{Q}(\cos2\pi/p,\sin2\pi/p):\mathbb{Q}(\cos2\pi/p)]\frac{p-1}{2}$ from which the result follows.

Comment: Then $[\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p) : \mathbb{Q}(\cos 2\pi / p, \sin 2\pi / p)] = 1$?

Comment: You are right this is an error. In fact, this does not even make sense as $\sin2\pi/p$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$. I believe what I wrote now is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\zeta = \exp(\frac{2\pi i}{4p})$. Then $\zeta$ is a primitive $(4p)$-th root of unity, and since $2p-1$ is coprime to $4p$, it follows that there is a Galois automorphism (let us call it $\sigma$) of ${\mathbb Q}(\zeta)$ such that $\sigma(\zeta)=\zeta^{2p-1}$.

From Euler's formula we deduce

$$
\cos\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{p}\bigg)=\frac{\zeta^4-\zeta^{2p-4}}{2}, \
\sin\bigg(\frac{2\pi}{p}\bigg)=\frac{\zeta^{p-4}-\zeta^{p+4}}{2} \tag{1}
$$

Also, straightforward computations show that
$$
\sigma(\zeta^4)=-\zeta^{2p-4},\sigma(\zeta^{2p-4})=-\zeta^{4},
\sigma(\zeta^{p-4})=\zeta^{p+4},\sigma(\zeta^{p+4})=\zeta^{p-4}, \tag{2}
$$

Combining (1) with (2), we see that $\sigma$ fixes $\cos\big(\frac{2\pi}{p}\big)$ and sends $\sin\big(\frac{2\pi}{p}\big)$ to its opposite. It follows that $\sin\big(\frac{2\pi}{p}\big)\not\in{\mathbb Q}\big(\cos\big(\frac{2\pi}{p}\big)\big)$.